# Turn javascript object into unordered list

Tags: javascript, list, object, recursion

I have data like:

```
var data = {
itemOne:{id:"itemOne",parent:false},
itemTwo:{id:"itemTwo",parent:"itemOne"},
itemThree:{id:"itemThree",parent:"itemTwo"},
itemFour:{id:"itemFour",parent:"itemTwo"},
itemFive:{id:"itemFive",parent:false},
itemSix:{id:"itemSix",parent:"itemOne"},
itemSeven:{id:"itemSeven",parent:"itemFive"},
};
```

So each sub object in the main data object specifies its ID and its parent, and if it doesn't have a parent it is marked as false. What I need to do is output this into a multi-level unordered list, so it should look like:

- item-one

  - item-two

    - item-three
    - item-four

    item-six
- item-five

  - item-seven

Now this data is a simplified sample but the list may be more than 3 levels deep and presented in a random order. I know the solution will involve some kind of recursion but I have no idea how to do this. So far I have built out the following:

```js
var myList = '<ul>';

for(item in data){
  var id = data[item]['id'];
  var parent = data[item]['parent'];
  
  if(parent == false){
  
  myList += '<li>'+id+'</li>';
  //no idea what to do here
  }
}

myList += '</ul>';
```

UPDATE: some of the answers have turned my data object into an array. It's important the data stays as an object as this is the value I am provided with and I can't change that. My thoughts so far is that I may need to first convert my data into a multilevel object structure, and then once that's completed convert the multilevel object into an unordered list. That way the data can be more easily manipulated into the proper hierarchy initially.

Comment: you should use a dfs serach.

Comment: Why you dont just nest the objects with a children property or something? And you need a function that you will call inside itself to make it recursive.

Comment: Key/value pairs in an object are not ordered. If you want to enforce/preserve order, you need to use an array.

Comment: @Teemoh unfortunately I don't have control over the original format of the data as it is supplied by WordPress. But I understand what you're saying.

Comment: @torazaburo yep understood. I am not too fussy about the order as long as the hierarchy is correct that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this logic, hope it may help as this draw the tree structure with deep down child nodes.

this is the array that I have created for quick reference and yes I make the use of recursion,

https://codepen.io/iamlalit/pen/ZyLLyQ

```js
var arr = [
        {'id':"itemOne" ,'parentid' : false},
        {'id':"itemTwo" ,'parentid' : "itemOne"},
        {'id':"itemThree" ,'parentid' : "itemTwo"},
        {'id':"itemFour" ,'parentid' : "itemTwo"},
        {'id':"itemFive" ,'parentid' : "itemTwo"},
        {'id':"itemSix" ,'parentid' : "itemSeven"},
        {'id':"itemSeven" ,'parentid' : "itemOne"}
];

unflatten = function( array, parent, tree ){
   
    tree = typeof tree !== 'undefined' ? tree : [];
    parent = typeof parent !== 'undefined' ? parent : { id: 0 };
        
    var children = _.filter( array, function(child){ return child.parentid == parent.id; });
    
    if( !_.isEmpty( children )  ){
        if( parent.id == 0 ){
           tree = children;   
        }else{
           parent['children'] = children
        }
        _.each( children, function( child ){ unflatten( array, child ) } );                    
    }
    
    return tree;
}

tree = unflatten( arr );
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + (JSON.stringify(tree, null, " "))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Without underscore

https://codepen.io/iamlalit/pen/ZyLLyQ

```js
var arr = [
        {'id':"itemOne" ,'parentid' : false},
        {'id':"itemTwo" ,'parentid' : "itemOne"},
        {'id':"itemThree" ,'parentid' : "itemTwo"},
        {'id':"itemFour" ,'parentid' : "itemTwo"},
        {'id':"itemFive" ,'parentid' : false},
        {'id':"itemSix" ,'parentid' : "itemSeven"},
        {'id':"itemSeven" ,'parentid' : "itemOne"}
];

unflatten = function( array, parent, tree ){
   
    tree = typeof tree !== 'undefined' ? tree : [];
    parent = typeof parent !== 'undefined' ? parent : { id: 0 };
        
    var children = array.filter( function(child){ return child.parentid == parent.id; });
    
    if( children  ){
        if( parent.id == 0 ){
           tree = children;   
        }else{
           parent['children'] = children
        }
        $.each( children, function( k, child ){ unflatten( array, child ) } );                    
    }
    
    return tree;
}

tree = unflatten( arr );
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + (JSON.stringify(tree, null, " "))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not familiar with underscore.js. Is it possible to do this without underscore? I don't want to be ungrateful but I was hoping to get into an unordered list format i.e. <ul><li></li></ul> etc.

Comment: Please have a look to the updated answer without underscore

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out in more detail. The answer still doesn't put it into a list format. But the more I am thinking about it, I think I may need to first put it into a child parent object structure, and then convert this structure into a list - so a two step process. Your answer also changes the data structure as it wraps it in an array when my data is in an object. I can't change the data source given to me.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily using JavaScript.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="unorderedList"></ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var data = [
  {'id':"itemOne" ,'parentId' : false},
  {'id':"itemTwo" ,'parentId' : "itemOne"},
  {'id':"itemThree" ,'parentId' : "itemTwo"},
  {'id':"itemFour" ,'parentId' : "itemTwo"},
];

var list = '';

data.forEach(function(parent) {
  list += '<li>' + parent.data;
  list += '<ul>';

  data.forEach(function(item) {
    if(item.parentId == parent.id)
      list += '<li>' + item.data + '</li>;
  }

  list += '</ul>';  //inner <ul> close
  list += '</li>';  //outer <li> close
} 

document.getElementById('unorderedList').innerHTML = list;
```